# saving/updating data from a query in a dataset to save back to all the tables involved (visual basic)

Tags: sql, vb.net, data-binding, dataset, tableadapter

I have imported an access database into my VB project. In the access database that I have imported I have a multi-table query providing me with the data I need for my schedule form in vb.
What I want to know is ... Is the a difference in saving the data when using the results of a query? What is the correct code to update all the tables involved with this query when data is changed and saved on the form? I used the following...

```
Me.Validate()
Me.Query_Print_ScheduleBindingSource.EndEdit()
Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.ProductionMgmtDatabaseDataSet)
```

But had an error message.

> TableAdapterManager contains no connection information. Set each TableAdapterManager TableAdapter property to a valid TableAdapter instance

Any Help/Tips Appreciated.

Comment: and the error message was . .  .?

Comment: TableAdapterManager contains no connection information. Set each TableAdapterManager TableAdapter property to a valid TableAdapter instance.

Comment: then your tableadpateramanager does not know about the tableadapters its supposed to be working with.  You need to associate the ta's you are using to the corresponding manager - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629327.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link. Do i need to associate all the tables the query drags data from or just the query itself? Will the query i imported from access update all the tables?

Comment: The role of the tamanager is to co-ordinate the tableadapters in multi-table updates, where you may have added, modified, and deleted rows in parent and child tables. Assuming you have foreign key constraints, the adds need to be done parent first, then child, while the deletes need to be done child, then parent.  The ta manager takes care of this, saving you a bit of boilerplate code; therefore it has to know about the corresponding tableadapters. EAch table in your dataset will have a corresponding tableadapter; the ta manager needs  references to all of these.

Comment: Me.TableAdapterManager.ScheduleTableAdapter = New ProductionMgmtDatabaseDataSetTableAdapters.ScheduleTableAdapter was added to my code along with a few more for other tables. The error message is now gone but the dataset isn't saving the modified data back to the database ??Any ideas??

Comment: Put a breakpoint immediately after the .EndEdit line, hover over the dataset with the mouse and a dataset viewer will pop up. See if the changes have been written to the tables.

Comment: It was the query i created in access!! I created a select query which would update back to the tables... To resolve my problem i passed the changed values to variables and passed the variables through a function to another page where i opened the tables required to update. The values stored in the variables i then used to update the tables respectively. Maybe the long way around things but got what i required in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Incase you have used a strongly typed dataset, once you drag and drop your controls onto the form, a TableAdapter manager is Added, this table adapter manager has properties that need you to specify each individual table adapter as indicated on the form. For example if you have a customerTableAdapter and OrdersTable Adapter with local instances on the form, all you need is to indicate these in the TableAdapter.